# Run msys2 shell in VSCode terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, command-prompt, msys2, devkitpro

I am working with ([a customized install of](https://devkitpro.org/wiki/Getting_Started)) msys2, and I would like to make it run in the VSCode integrated terminal. However, it doesen't seem to want to run there. Unlike normal msys, it has `msys2_shell.bat` & `msys2_shell.cmd`. It seems to always open up a separate shell window, but I don't want this to always happen, I would like to keep it integrated so I can use shortcuts and such. I already tried the `-no-start` option. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I want to prevent it from opening a new window and want it to run in the integrated VSCode terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation; I've edited the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msys2_shell.cmd -no-start -defterm` could work.  Other than that, you can invoke Bash directly if you remember to set `MSYSTEM` and invoke a login shell: `C:\msys64\usr\bin\env MSYSTEM=MSYS /usr/bin/bash -li`

For more details, see https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/.

Comment: Also just wanted to say I had to use the `-here` flag as well, crashed without it.